# How to make an image triangle and give a stroke around it?

Tags: html, css, geometry, shapes, stroke

I want an image to be in a triangle shape with 10px black border. I can make the shape but failing to give stroke around it. How do I do this ?

Comment: show us how you made the shape and we can help.

Comment: Uploaded here
http://jsfiddle.net/A9Zbj/129/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a webkit only solution:

```
<div class="triangle">&#9650;</div>

.triangle{
    -webkit-text-stroke: 12px black;
    color : transparent;
    font-size:200px;
}
```

Here is a non-webkit solution:

```
<div class="new">
    <div class="empty"></div>
</div>

.new {
    position: relative;
    width:0;
    border-bottom:solid 50px black;
    border-right:solid 30px transparent;
    border-left:solid 30px transparent;
}
.new .empty {
    position: absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:-21px;
    width:0;
    border-bottom:solid 36px white;
    border-right:solid 21px transparent;
    border-left:solid 21px transparent;
}
```

<kbd>[CodePen for ease](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/Ehbox)</kbd>

Comment: How to add the image inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `canvas`

```
// stroke color
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.strokeText('Hello World!', x, y);
```